# I couldn't make this programm run as I wanted

Tags: java

```
public class Phone {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String numbers[][] = { { "Tom", "555-3322" }, { "Mary", " 555-8976" },
                { "Jon", "555-1037" }, { "Rachel", "555-1400" } };

        int i;

        if (args.length != 1)
            System.out.println("Usage: java Phone <name>");
        else {
            for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
                if (numbers[i][0].equals(args[0])) {
                    System.out.println(numbers[i][0] + ": " + numbers[i][1]);
                    break;
                }
                if (i == numbers.length)
                    ;
                System.out.println("Name not found.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So after I trie to run theses line of code,I didn't get any other result, apart from the first sysout statement.

Comment: What was the expected result?

Comment: Don't you mean `if(numbers.length != 1)`?

Comment: Likely `args.length` does not equal 1.

Comment: I formatted your code and tried to add a little more meaning of your intent. I didn't try to change drastically entirely of my opinion. your question doesn't make sense. What isn't working? What do you intend this code to do?

Comment: This code appears to work fine for me. Running with arg of Tom prints: "Tom: 555-3322" as expected. Agree with WonderWorld that perhaps your command line execution of the program is not passing in args as you expect.

Comment: i supposed to launch Mary's phone but i got the statement " Usage: java Phone <name> " for no reasson i can't run with arg of Mary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has few errors. From

> Usage: java Phone

it looks like expected content of `args` array should be `"Phone"` `<name>` which are two elements so

```
if(args.length != 1)
```

is not valid condition. You probably should replace it with

```
if (args.length < 2)
```

---

Other problem is that `<name>` is second element in `args` array stored in `args[1]` so

```
if(numbers[i][0].equals(args[0]))
```

should be

```
if(numbers[i][0].equals(args[1])) //we want to compare name, not "Phone" string
```

---

Last problems involve

```
if (i == numbers.length);
    System.out.println("Name not found.");
```

- inside for loop `i` will never be equal `number.length` because `for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)` loop iterates only if `i<number.length`. So this condition should be replaced with

  ```
  if (i == numbers.length -1)
  ```
- there is semicolon right after this condition which represents empty instruction, which means that

  ```
  if (i == numbers.length - 1);
      System.out.println("Name not found.");
  ```

  is essentially same as

  ```
  if (i == numbers.length - 1)
      ;
  System.out.println("Name not found.");
  ```

  which means that execution of `System.out.println("Name not found.");` doesn't depend on result of `if` condition.

  To solve this problem simply remove this additional `;`, and to avoid this problem always surround code which should depend of `if` `else` `for` `while` inside blocks `{...}`.

Comment: I have followed your steps but I continue like the at the begin

Comment: Can you post at http://pastebin.com/ your current code and share link? Also how are you trying to run it?

Comment: i have made that what you said but as like the begin dont launch any phone number.I think I'm not running good args.

Comment: You forgot to remove `;` after `if(i == numbers.length-1)` which as explained at end of my answer makes `System.out.println("Name not found.");` independent from `if`. Also consider printing your arguments you used. Maybe this will help you track your problems (use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(args));`).

Comment: I continue doing it grown but it's fine dude,i will make a new one,ty for your help as well

Answer (score 0):

You might be running this java code without argument specified.
eg. **java Phone** will give output as **Usage: java Phone** 

But if you run it with an argument , you will surely have a output.
eg.  **java Phone Tom** will give output as **Tom: 555-3322**

Answer (score 0):

There are two small bugs in your code. One is related to the fact that you are not using parentheses for the `if` code

```
if(i == numbers.length);
    System.out.println("Name not found.");
```

The problem here is not easy to spot. There is a semicolon after the if statement, which means there is no code block for the if case and `System.out.println` is always executed.

The second problem is you check for `i == numbers.length`. This is never true inside your `for-loop`, as the array index is zero based. Means when you have four entries the highest index is three. So this condition would never be true.

You should fix the code like this.

```
if(i == numbers.length-1) {
    System.out.println("Name not found.");
}
```